Measure reuse of methods
I need to count how many times any method under a specific package is called (similar to Hieracy but in run time, to export the results)
For example:
The Method setA is called 17 times, the method setB is called 3 times...
Based on this answer I succeeded in extracting all the methods in the implementation classes, but I don't know how to find all the uses in the production code.
public static List<Class<?>> find(String scannedPackage) {
    String scannedPath = scannedPackage.replace(PKG_SEPARATOR, DIR_SEPARATOR);
    URL scannedUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(scannedPath);
    if (scannedUrl == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(BAD_PACKAGE_ERROR, scannedPath, scannedPackage));
    }
    File scannedDir = new File(scannedUrl.getFile());
    List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    for (File file : scannedDir.listFiles()) {
        classes.addAll(find(file, scannedPackage));
    }
    return classes;
}

private static List<Class<?>> find(File file, String scannedPackage) {
    List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    String resource = scannedPackage + PKG_SEPARATOR + file.getName();
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : file.listFiles()) {
            classes.addAll(find(child, resource));
        }
    } else if (resource.endsWith(CLASS_FILE_SUFFIX)) {
        int endIndex = resource.length() - CLASS_FILE_SUFFIX.length();
        String className = resource.substring(0, endIndex);
        if (className.endsWith("ActivityImpl")) {
            try {
                classes.add(Class.forName(className));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignore) {
            }
        }

    }
    return classes;
}

and use it like this:
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Class<?>> classes = find("com.my.project.activities");
    for (Class c : classes) {
        System.out.println("Class name: " + c.getName());
        System.out.print("Methods: ");
        Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            System.out.print(method.getName() + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}

how can I count the uses of each method?
More info: Java 21, Spring Boot 3.2.4

Sounds like you need a profiler

The best way for counting methods calls is using aspects. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html
Aspect oriented programming seems hard at beginning, but it gives you freedom in actions and, what is more important, it will leave your methods intact. Here is a short example:
First we have to include dependency
If we use gradle it will be in the file build.gradle
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')

Include the analog in maven.xml if maven is used
We will write a class with methods for testing
@Component
public class ClassWithMethods {

    // method under consideration
    public void setA() {
    }

    public void setB() {
    }

}

Look, we will not change this class for method calls counting.
Then we write aspect
@Aspect
@Component // this aspect will be a spring bean
public class AspectForCountingMethodCalls {

    public static AtomicLong setACounter = new AtomicLong(0L);
    public static AtomicLong setBCounter = new AtomicLong(0L);

    @Before("execution (* setA(..))") // executed before every call setA
    public void countSetACall() {
        setACounter.getAndIncrement(); // increase counter
    }

    @Before("execution (* setB(..))") // executed before every call setB
    public void countSetBCall() {
        setBCounter.getAndIncrement(); // increase counter
    }

}

And now we can test it and enjoy
@SpringBootTest
public class AspectTest {

    @Autowired
    ClassWithMethods classWithMethods;

    @Test
    void testCounter() {
        // call setA 17 times
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            classWithMethods.setA();
        }
        // call setB 3 times
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            classWithMethods.setB();
        }
        // verify that our aspect works
        assertEquals(17L, AspectForCountingMethodCalls.setACounter.get());
        assertEquals(3L, AspectForCountingMethodCalls.setBCounter.get());
    }
}

We can do much more things with aspects but it is out of scope of this answer

That could be a good idea, I  can use AOP and run E2E flows... Thank you
